# Create a dictionary where letters of the alphabet are the key?

Tags: python

I have a tuple that contains random words such as

```
words = ("Apple","Charlie","Papa","Uniform","Tango","Echo","Romeo")
```

and I want to sort these into a dictionary like

```
dict = {"A": "Apple","C": "Charlie", "P": "Papa", "U" : "Uniform"....}
```

I know I need to initialize the dictionary and create a for loop to look through the tuple, but I don't know how to sort by letter.

Comment: The dictionary data structure is not ordered one. Use list instead.

Comment: Do you actually *need* it to be sorted? If you just want to be able to look up the word from its first letter, then `d = {w[0]: w for w in words}` (don't name your own variable `dict`) will do the job and you never have to worry about the order it's in.

Comment: You don't need to sort anything. Just use `dictionary["A"]`, for example.

Comment: Note that Jon's suggestion is only correct if there's only one word per initial letter (which is probably the case in your data).

Comment: Do you really mean "sort", or do you just want a dictionary (which as @abilinx says has no order) like the one in your example? Also: what happens if two words start with the same letter?

Comment: In case you want the contents of the tuple ordered (did you mean that?): you cannot sort a tuple. You can however extract an ordered list out of it: sorted(list((myTuple)))

Answer (score 2):

You can use dict comprehensions.

```
>>> words = ("Apple","Charlie","Papa","Uniform","Tango","Echo","Romeo")
>>> mydict = {value[0]: value for value in words}
>>> print(mydict)
{'A': 'Apple', 'C': 'Charlie', 'E': 'Echo', 'P': 'Papa', 'R': 'Romeo', 'U': 'Uniform', 'T': 'Tango'}
```

It will not be ordered, but if you need that pass it through

```
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(mydict.items()))
```

Comment: No need for the `key`-- the tuples will sort on the first element anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For the case you've mentioned, it's easy:

```
d = {}
for word in words:
    d[word[0]] = word
```

Of course, the normal caveats apply (dicts aren't ordered so there's no filtering involved, if `"Adam"` and `"Apple"` are both in your input, only the second will find its way into the output, etc).  To take care of the latter problem, you might want to consider a `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for word in words:
    d[word[0]].append(word)
```

which will leave you with a dict of characters mapped to a list.  And, once you have this, if you really want it to be "sorted" by key, you can do that with a `collections.OrderedDict` after the fact:

```
odict = OrderedDict()
for key in sorted(d):  # d is the defaultdict from the last step.
    odict[key] = d[key]
```

Comment: I like your idea about an `defaultdict` in any case where there might be more than one value starting with thesame letter. :)

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus -- I was wondering the same thing :-).  Tis the way of the StackOverflow sometimes . . . Perhaps it was because I didn't use a comprehension but I figured we should probably get OP walking before we try to teach him/her how to run.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the OP's desired output has strings as values, not lists, but this is more robust, so at most that's worth a comment and a no-vote.

Comment: @mgilson, seems there is a typo in your answer. Did you really intend 'd[word[0]].append(words)' and not 'd[word[0]].append(word)'?

Comment: @user3885927 -- Thanks.  There was a typo ... Maybe that's why someone downvoted :-)

Comment: @DSM -- I think that anytime you answer a somewhat underspecified question you run the risk of downvotes just because someone might have different ideas about what the question means...